# Is it possibly to remarry my wife after three talaqs?

Tags: talaq

I was married with my ex-wife for 18 years. Before we got married my ex-wife was pregnant. As it was a void one, I gave talaq and remarried her once again. Subsequently, we were living happily until we encountered some differences and again I gave talaq. Subsequently we remarried again and was stable for sometime. Finally in 2012 I gave talaq again. I want to remarry her. However we have had technically 3 talaqs; my question is whether it is possible to marry her without her marrying another person?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking your time to take our [tour] and check our [help] to learn how this page works. You should know that there's no way out of this as Quran is crystal clear about the 3rd talaq http://legacy.quran.com/2/229-230

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - consult a scholar, otherwise advice by lay people may affect your marriage!

In a nutshell, as you have given three talaqs, you are technically divorced. Its not possible to marry her without her marrying another person. This is the severeity to enable people to understand that their actions will be accountable.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to add an evidence to support your claims (see [answer])!